# VSC C Include errors detected

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I keep getting the errors `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\GIT\CS-262-004\HelloWorld.c) will be provided by the Tag Parser.C/C++(1696)` and `cannot open source file "stdio.h"`

from the include statement I have tried Reinstalling the GCC from MINGW and I have added the file to the Path, I am using VSC so i added the C/C++ extension by microsoft and Code Runner by Jun han.

edit: added a semicolon after the printf statement and errors weren't fixed

My Code:
FileName  -  HelloWorld.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 // printf() displays the string inside quotation
 printf("Hello, World!");
 return 0;
}
```

.vscode files
c_cpp_proporties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
```

settings.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "HelloWorld.c": "c"
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Try to run `gcc` from Command Prompt and see if it's working.

Comment: @rohan bari, i ran jusy gcc and get no input files but when i run gcc --version i get an outut of Gcc 6.3.0

Comment: It's now clear that something's wrong with your VSCode configuration. Try to share your `.vscode` contained JSON code by editing your question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I installed the mingw64 (with win32 instead of Posix) Please check the following:
- Compiler Path correct  
- reload the window (CTRL+P -> "Developer: Reload Window") after changing the   c_cpp_properties.json  
- try double backslash "\\" isntead of forward slash "/" for filepaths.